# Wpf class connect with main window

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I recently moved from Windows applications to WPF . The programming language I using is the visual basic net . My question is how to connect how to my own class and how to send the parameter from main application window. If this question is duplicate then send me link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just pass the parameter in the ctor

[Instance Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)

```
class CoOrds
{
    public int x, y;

    // Default constructor: 
    public CoOrds()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    // A constructor with two arguments: 
    public CoOrds(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // Override the ToString method: 
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (String.Format("({0},{1})", x, y));
    }
}
```